# How to use same setOnClickListener for mutliple functions in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have this setOnClickListener that first check if the user logged in then if the user logged in will run the function as below:

```
like.setOnClickListener {
            val sharedPreference2 = context?.getSharedPreferences("isLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val fbtoken = sharedPreference2?.getString("UserToken", "false")
            if(fbtoken.equals("false"))
            {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context).create()
                val optionDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                val layoutInflator = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
                val dialogView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.alert_reg, null)
                val goreg = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.confirmation_reg)
                val cancel = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cancel_reg)
                builder.setCancelable(false)
                builder.setView(dialogView)


                goreg?.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(context, SignupActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }


                cancel?.setOnClickListener {

                    builder.dismiss()

                }



                builder.show()

            }
            else
            {
                postLike(position, it.context)
                like.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked)
            }

        }
```

So the this setOnClickListener first will check the login and in "else" will post in API.

I'm trying to use same setOnClickListener used above if the user click again , it will delete it from API

I tried to replace "else" with "if" and "else" like the code below:

```
if (fbtoken.equals("true")){
                postLike(position, it.context)
                like.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked)
            }else{
                like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like)
                deleteLike(position, it.context)
            }
```

But now it delete it from API only

Its something similar to IG like button if I click first time the button it will post the like and if I click again it will delete it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way would be, not to call setImageResouce everytime user clicks on the image but have selector which would have two states like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_address_item_bg"android:state_selected="false"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_selected_address_bg"  
    android:state_selected="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_selected_address_bg"  />

 </selector>
```

you should set this xml as src parameter of image view or whataver view it is .

after that you should change state of view respectively according to user action

```
 likeButton.setonCLickListener {
  it.isSelected = !it.isSelected
    if (it.isSelected) {
       postLike()
} else {
       postUnlike()
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my question

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value saved in the preferences. You need to update the value to **true** **false** as clicks of button.

```
if (fbtoken.equals("true")){
   postLike(position, it.context)
   like.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked)
   fbtoken = sharedPreference2?.putString("UserToken", "false")
}else{
   like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like)
   deleteLike(position, it.context)
   fbtoken = sharedPreference2?.putString("UserToken", "true")
}
```

Comment: its the same issue, it delete only, when i click again it doesn't post

Comment: Save the values by using putString method.